# How do you install software center?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, update-manager

I searched for and ran the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
```

But I still don't have software center.  I got this error...

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch "//mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/universe/source/Sources"  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch "//mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/main/source/Sources"  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch "//mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/restricted/source/Sources"  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these commands? Giving us some context would be great.

Comment: The title of the thread explains what I want to achieve.

Comment: In Zesty, there is no package for Software-center in the Ubuntu package archives.  There is a `gnome-software`,  `ubuntu-software`, `lubuntu-software-center` and `ubuntu-kylin-software-center` - perhaps one of these is what you are looking for?

Comment: If you don't understand the Q:  why do you feel the need to reply?

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the repository you use has take down all three repositories. I checked their ftp servers, and these three are not present at all.

```
mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/universe/source/Sources
mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/main/source/Sources
mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/restricted/source/Sources
```

So, you will receive 404 Not Found error when attempting to connect to these repositories.

It is adviced that you change your repositories in `Ubuntu Settings --> Software and Updates --> Ubuntu Software` and under `Download from:` choose Ubuntu's `Main Server` or `Server from your country`.

[image: Imgur]

Or, you can open a new terminal, enter root and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`. You will see something like this:

```
# sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _zesty zapus_ - Release i386 (201xxxxx.x)]/ zesty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
deb-src http://mirrors.sonic.net/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
#...
```

Change all `mirrors.sonic.net` into `archive.ubuntu.com`.

After so, run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gnome-software` and that should work fine now.

### **(Update: Zesty do not use `software-center` anymore, use `gnome-software` or `ubuntu-software` instead.)**

If you know what other packages you are trying to install, you can use Synaptic Package Manager or directly use `apt-get` to install the packages you want.

Comment: Thank you for your feed back Cynplytholowazy !    The software the image in your reply portrays "Software and Updates" is no longer listed in my Ubuntu system settings.   This is the package I need to reinstall.  I have searched and tried numerous sudo commands with no success.